# Should a table of contents be followed by a pagebreak

Tags: latex, table-of-contents

I'm writing a report on a java program for school. Should I put a pagebreak after the table of contents so as to start the new chapter in a new page?

Comment: `\chapter` should do that automagically in the `report` class. Don't fiddle with this yourself: The class should take of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally yes, because you wouldn't really want the table of contents *and* the beginning of a chapter on one page. It looks neater, and easier to manage when you finally print it out.